# Ubuntu maven The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly

Tags: maven, ubuntu, java-home

I installed maven in Ubuntu 22.04 and I am getting the next error when I try a `mvn clean install` command:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

My JAVA_HOME has the next value:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JAVA_HOME` needs to be one level up - `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`